# Rails param["value"] is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason, one of my params (file upload) always is nil. Here is the params hash in the exception page that is shown:

```
{"utf8"=>"âœ“",
 "_method"=>"put",
 ...

 "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe7fa1dd460 @original_filename="rp.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"rp.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/44/xrz6nqg91_l_gzmhxt8s771c0000gn/T/RackMultipart20111107-12870-nguhuw>>},
 "commit"=>"Update",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

In my controller, I have `if params["avatar"]`, but avatar is always returning nil.

Comment: You've done a bad job omitting code. We need to see what the `...` represents to answer this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`avatar` is likely nested within another element. By omitting important details, we can't tell, but I *can* tell that your dump has an unbalanced `}` on the line starting with `@tempfile`, so it's likely that the matching `{` appears *before* `"avatar"=>` and thus it is nested within another hash.

You might try something like `params[:user][:avatar]`, or whatever the actual name of your model is.

Comment: Wow thanks, I totally missed that. The start of the curly brace is before `"user"` which means I can access it by using `params[:user][:avatar]`

Comment: `params[:user][:avatar]`. Called it :)